# Сохранение png файла в SD card

Tags: android, imageview

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы изображение сохранялось при нажатии кнопки на SD карту? Я совсем новичок, а приложение срочно нужно. Здесь встречал подобные вопросы, но они или не совсем то, что нужно, или попросту я не понимаю, куда какой код вставлять. Буду признателен за помощь!

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.